# Function $ f(x,y)=x+\frac{y^3}{3} $ cut the xy-plane in a cutting-curve $h$. Find the tangent fuction of h in point$ P(9,-3)$.

Tags: calculus, 3d, curves

$$ f(x,y)=x+\frac{y^3}{3} , D(f)=\text{(x,y)}\in R |(x^2 +y^2\le2)  $$

So what i thinking here is find the function h, then find the tangent. But i dont know how to do or is there another way? Thank you for reading

Comment: How does f cut the plane?  What is h?

Comment: Sorry i typed wrong. Just editted that to f(x,y). h is the fuction of the curve which is formed by the cutting of f(x,y) and the xy-plane

Comment: So the curve is 3x + y$^3$ = 0?   What is D(f) supposed to be?

Comment: D(f) mean the definition range of the function f. Because it is only a part of the excercise and the other part need the definition range to be completed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you help me more with how to find the slope in order to find tangent function of h:= 3x+y^3=0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to find the tangent of 3x + y$^3$ = 0 at (9,-3).
As 3 + 3y$^2$y' = 0, y'(x) = -/y$^2$.
At the given point, y'(9) = -1/9 = m.
The tangent is y + 3 = m(x - 9).